# Compiler-error on Online Judge,"wimplicit-function-declaration"

Tags: c

I given the problem to convert inputted string into certain condition like:

```
I = 1
R = 2
E = 3
A = 4
S = 5
G = 6
T = 7
B = 8
P = 9
O = 0
```

And all inputted string must be uppercase string.

Here is my code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>


int main(){ 
    char a[100];

    int i;
    scanf("%[^\n]s", a);
    strupr(a);
    int length=strlen(a);
    getchar();


    for(i=0;i<length;i++){
        if(a[i]=='I'){
            a[i]='1';
        }
        else if(a[i]=='R'){
            a[i]='2';
        }
        else if(a[i]=='E'){
            a[i]='3';
            a[i]='4';
        }
        else if(a[i]=='O'){
            a[i]='O';
        }
        else if(a[i]=='S'){
            a[i]='5';
        }
        else if(a[i]=='G'){
            a[i]='6';
        }
        else if(a[i]=='A'){
        }
        else if(a[i]=='T'){
            a[i]='7';
        }
        else if(a[i]=='B'){
            a[i]='8';
        }
        else if(a[i]=='P'){
            a[i]='9';
        }
    }

    printf("%s\n", a);
    return 0;

}
```

But the online judge keep saying compiler-error:

> Compiling failed with exitcode 1, compiler output: secet.c: In
>   function 'main': secet.c:11:3: warning: implicit declaration of
>   function 'strupr' [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]    strupr(a);    ^
>   secet.c:8:3: warning: ignoring return value of 'scanf', declared with
>   attribute warn_unused_result [-Wunused-result]    scanf("%[^\n]s", a);
>   ^ /tmp/ccWRs5uD.o: In function `main': secet.c:(.text.startup+0x73):
>   undefined reference to`strupr' collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit
>   status

Sorry if don't know although it's obvious, I'm new to programming. But in my compiler(dev-c++) it's working perfectly.

Comment: `strupr` is a nonstandard function.

Comment: It's not hard to write using `toupper` from `ctype.h`. https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/toupper.html